# Combine rows in Power Query based on a shared column value

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I have an export from quickbooks showing all outstanding invoices.  Each invoice consists of only 2 line items:  "Consulting Fee" and "Admin Fee".  The QB export creates a row for each of the line items.  They share a common column datapoint of "Invoice".

The data requires a lot of massaging so I'm doing that in Power Query.

How could I get the rows "merged" into single rows based on Invoice #, preferably within Power Query?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Power BI?

Answer (score 1):

Power Query has the "group by" functionality that I think could solve this. You can group by the Invoices# column and decide what happens to the other columns. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can Add a Custom Column with formula:

```
=[Column 1]+[Column 2]
```